# Inputselect value not binding correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor

I am trying to bind selected category id to the option the user selects but the id always defaults to 0 no matter what i select.

```
<EditForm Model="segment" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit" FormName="name" class="card w-50">

    <label>
        Name
    </label>

    <InputText @bind-Value="segment.Name"></InputText>

    <label>
        Description
    </label>

    <InputText @bind-Value="segment.Description"></InputText>

    <label>
        Category:
    </label>

    <InputSelect @bind-Value="SelectedCategoryId">
        @foreach (var category in Categories)
        {
            <option value="@category.Id">@category.Name</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>


    <input type="submit" value="Create a segment" />

</EditForm>


@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public SegmentModel segment { get; set; } = new();

    public int SelectedCategoryId { get; set; } 

    [Parameter]
    public List<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Categories = await manager._categoryRepository.GetAllCategoriesAsync();
    }

    private async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        // await manager._categoryRepository.AddCategoryAsync(Category);

        segment.CategoryId = SelectedCategoryId;
        await manager._segmentRepository.AddSegmentAsync(segment);
    }

    private void HandleCategorySelection(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        // Parse the selected value from the event args
        int selectedId = Convert.ToInt32(args.Value);

        // Set the SelectedCategoryId
        SelectedCategoryId = selectedId;
    }
}
```

Tried to bind the id of the selected option in the input select to an integer but it is always set to 0. The categories are initialized properly and the segment itself when i create it is also initialized properly.

Comment: When you debug does your HandleCategorySelection method execute? Wondering if you would have more luck binding your SelectedCategoryId to a member of the SegmentModel instead of a standalone member.

Comment: Hey! I tried binding it directly to segmentmodel.categoryId and that worked! I had to attach the entity before adding it to the database but it solved the problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@onchange` event attribute to your `InputSelect` element and set it to call your `HandleCategorySelection` method

```
<InputSelect @bind-Value="SelectedCategoryId" @onchange="HandleCategorySelection">
    @foreach (var category in Categories)
    {
        <option value="@category.Id">@category.Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```